# How to track lead/conversion origins

Tags: marketing

I've had a problem a couple times recently: a user has signed up for my product (http://sniphq.com) but I don't know exactly how the user found my site.

Is there a way, perhaps through Google Analytics, to see something like the following for each conversion?

1. Referred by Google search term "salon software"
2. Visited blog post "Why salon software?"
3. Visited Sign Up page
4. Created account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google analytics can be used for this type of tracking, but I think you're limited (at least in the free version) to tracking up to 20 objectives (called "Goals" by Google).

What you do is to go to your analytics page a set up individual Goals to track discrete actions.  These actions can be page visits, conversions, transactions, purchases, time spent on your site, etc.

You must define and set up the Goals you want to track on your Google Analytics page *before* any data and reports related to Goals becomes available.